# EXC Bad Access with Iterators

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator, exc-bad-access

I created this function that works with vectors, linked lists and double linked lists. The function takes a value and searches for it in the container.  If the vlaue is in the container than the function will insert the value right next to where it already exists. So, if `val=2` then `{3,2,5}` will become `{3,2,2,5}`. But if the value does not exist in the container, it is added to the back instead.

I wrote this function using iterators. It works just fine with a vector, however when I try to run it with a list or double linked list I get an Exc Bad Access error at the line `if (*it==val)`. I am not seeing what I did wrong.

```
template <class Container, class T>
void insertNextTo( Container &x, const T &val){
    typename Container::iterator it = x.begin();
    while (it!=x.end() && *it!=val){
        ++it;
    }
    if (*it == val){
        x.insert(it, val);
    }
    else{
        x.push_back(val);
    }
}
```

Edit: Thank you everyone! Your suggestion to change the `if` statement worked perfectly!

Comment: If the `val` is not found, then `if` condition derferences the end element which leads to UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if (*it == val)
```

to:

```
if (it != x.end())
```

If `val` isn't found in the container, the loop will end when `it == x.end()`. That points past the end of the array, so indirecting through it results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If the value does not exist yet, `it` will be equal to `end()` when the loop is finished, and you cannot dereference `end()`.  You need to change `if (*it == val)` to `if (it != x.end())` instead:

```
//if (*it == val){
if (it != x.end()){
    x.insert(it, val);
}
```

Alternatively, since you are only inserting one value, if you find `val` then you can do the `insert()` and exit the function immediately, and then `push_back()` only if the loop reaches the end of the container:

```
template <class Container, class T>
void insertNextTo( Container &x, const T &val ) {
    typename Container::iterator it = x.begin();
    while (it != x.end()) {
        if (*it == val) {
            x.insert(it, val);
            return;
        }
        ++it;
    }
    x.push_back(val);
}
```

In which case, you can simplify the code by using `std::find()` instead of a manual loop:

```
#include <algorithm>

template <class Container, class T>
void insertNextTo( Container &x, const T &val ) {
    typename Container::iterator it = std::find(x.begin(), x.end(), val);
    if (it != x.end()) {
        x.insert(it, val);
    } else {
        x.push_back(val);
    }
}
```

Or even this, since it is safe to `insert()` using the `end()` iterator, it is effectively the same as `push_back()`:

```
template <class Container, class T>
void insertNextTo( Container &x, const T &val ) {
    typename Container::iterator it = std::find(x.begin(), x.end(), val);
    x.insert(it, val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong but I believe your error comes from the fact that the when your iterator reaches the end of the list, it actually points to the address after the last bit of the list in memory, which may or may not be initialized and in scope, which causes your program to error.